# Was heisst dieser Regel, in dem das Verb an erster Stelle kommt und wird Kausalität bedeutet?

Tags: grammatical-case

> Grundsätzlich lassen sich drei verschiedene Funktionen unterscheiden:
>
> Erstens dient Geld als Tausch- beziehungsweise Zahlmittel. Zweitens
>   macht es den Wert von verschiedenen Gütern direkt vergleichbar und hat
>   drittens eine Wertaufbewahrungsfunktion.
>
> **Wird** **es** als Tausch- beziehungsweise Zahlungsmittel verwendet, wird **Geld** gegen Dienstleistungen oder Güter eingetauscht.

2 Warum steht die Name "Geld" nach dem Pronomen "es", soweit ich weiss, muss der Satz so sein"wird Geld ..., wird es gegen..."

Comment: @Janka: "Verberstnebensatz" muss eines der deutschen Wörter sein, die man mitunter erst versteht, wenn sie mit Bindestrichen, hier "Verb-Erst-Nebensatz", geschrieben werden. (Und ich hab' noch gegrübelt, was denn ein "Ver-berst" sein soll; ob das vielleicht ein Eigenname ist ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das angegebene Konstrukt besteht aus Haupt- und Nebensatz, wobei der Nebensatz untergeordnet ist. Die Reihenfolge von Haupt- und Nebensatz ist beliebig; in Deinem Beispiel steht der Nebensatz am Anfang. Andersherum wäre es so:

> Wird Geld gegen Dienstleistungen oder Güter eingetauscht, (dann) wird es
>   als Tausch- beziehungsweise Zahlungsmittel verwendet.

Folgende Möglichkeiten sind aber auch richtig (und in diesem Beispiel verändert sich die Bedeutung (kaum), da hier keine wirkliche Kausalität vorliegt und es so keine logische Unterordnung des einen Teils unter den anderen gibt.) :

> Wird es gegen Dienstleistungen oder Güter eingetauscht, wird Geld
>   als Tausch- beziehungsweise Zahlungsmittel verwendet.
>
> Wird Geld als Tausch- beziehungsweise Zahlungsmittel verwendet, wird
>   es gegen Dienstleistungen oder Güter eingetauscht.

Außerdem kann sich das »es« auch auf vorige Sätze beziehen.

Comment: Im Englischen ist das übrigens genauso: _You can do it, if you want_ versus _If you want, you can do it_.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Im Englischen ist die Bedingung durch das *if* aber eindeutig markiert. Im Deutschen kann sich in der genannten Form die Bedingung *ausschließlich* im ersten Satzteil befinden. Das wird anhand eines Beispiels, in dem die Kausalität tatsächlich nur in einer Richtung gegeben ist, klarer: Die inhaltlich zutreffende Aussage "Regnet es, wird die Straße nass." lässt sich nicht zu "Wird die Straße nass, regnet es." umdrehen, ohne unzutreffend zu werden (denn die Straße kann auch auf andere Weise nass werden).